# How to add 'easing' to animate/scrolltop

Tags: jquery

I am using the following function to create a scroll animation to anchor links:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate(
        {scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top}, 
        500 );
    return false;
});
```

I would like to add easing. However, when I add 'easing' after '500' it breaks the script:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate(
        {scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top}, 
        500, easing );
    return false;
});
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You may be interested in using the jquery.scrollTo plugin: [jquery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: Where are you defining `easing`? It should be a string.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First you need include jQuery.UI script then your code should look:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var top = $('body').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: top
    },500, 'easeOutExpo');

    return false;
});
```

For your information:

**Easing**

> The remaining parameter of .animate() is a string naming an easing
>   function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the
>   animation progresses at different points within the animation. The
>   only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins,
>   most notably the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) suite.

---

### Why your code not working:

1. Because you use `this` which was in scope of animation method and
   reference to `body` and `html` objects.
2. Because `easing` is not a method. Is a string type of animation property so you need
   write it as string for example: `'easeOutExpo'` or `"easeOutExpo"`.

Comment: I get ... #<Object> has no method 'easing'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30363/discussion-between-woocash-and-user1444027)