# Extra smooth scroll to div id jQuery - slow start, fast middle and slow end

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

How do I change the scroll speed during an scroll event?

My idea is to start the scroll event slow, speed it up in the middle section and slow it down close the aim. There different attempts for the mouse wheel event eg. from [Nathan Rutzky](http://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed)

*I think it works over the time variable of [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), but I need a hint how to implement it...*

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('data-menuanchor')).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#div {
    min-height:1100px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff0000, #ff8f8f); 
}
#myDiv {
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
.button:nth-of-type(1){
    left: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button" data-menuanchor="#myDiv">button down</div>
<div class="button" data-menuanchor="#div">button up</div>
<div id="div">
    <p>Content</p>        
</div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: probably using `easing` function with `ease-in-out` value

Comment: which is... the default. https://api.jqueryui.com/easings/ (note that many of the easing styles at that page are for jQuery UI only. swing is default.)

Comment: @KevinB I don't think its default? I think default is `linear`

Comment: it's definitely swing.

Comment: @KevinB I realized that but the difference is not to big... And I though about an acceleration up to the fastest point (half the way)...

Comment: I think `easeInOutQuint` or `easeInOutQuart` would be okay for the required animation..

Comment: Right. so you'll want to include an easing plugin that implements the easing you want. The easiest would be to pull one from jQuery UI. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effect.js#L1584-L1631

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16680209/2887133

Comment: @RohitKumar I got [the idea](https://jsfiddle.net/jdng6r2n/)... but its still not the combination I want - slow->fast->slow.

Comment: @wittich You can even create your custom easing function too.. just search for it.. because I don't know much jQuery.. but I'm sure that you can create you custom animation function to make the animation feel as you want.